# mysql simple subquery problem

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
table user
____________________________________________
id    name    nickname    info_id
1     john    apple        11
2     paul    banana       12
3     pauline melon        13

table info
_____________________________________________
id    job         location 
11    model       usa
12    engineer    russia
13    seller      brazil

result I want
______________________________________________
1   john    apple    model     usa
```

my query

left join:

```
select * from user a left join info b on b.id = a.info_id where a.id=1
```

subquery:

```
select a.*, b.* from (user a, info b) where b.id = a.info_id
```

which is better?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what the question is. Are you saying that you think there's a query that's more efficient than both of those?

Comment: Are you experiencing performance problems now?  Can you post the entire query?\

Comment: @Matchu Yes, @Abe Miessler don't have performance problem yet

Comment: Your two queries are almost identical except the second is performing an inner join. Actual join syntax is a matter of personal taste though I prefer the former.

Comment: As Phil says, this is preference. The query optimizer should in such as simple case produce the same steps for both. As far as "more" performance you are better off thinking about caching on the application side before worrying about such a simple query's execution plan.

Comment: @okGood: The two queries are not equivalent. For 2 reasons. The first has `LEFT JOIN` while the second has an (implicit) `INNER JOIN`. Second, the `a.id=1` condition appears in one query and not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.`name`, a.`nickname`, b.`job`, b.`location` 
FROM `user` AS a
LEFT JOIN `info` AS b 
    ON ( a.`info_id` = b.`id` )
```

That should be pretty efficient. Try using MySQL EXPLAIN if you are concerned (also make sure there are indexes on the ID fields): 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html

---

**UPDATE**

After seeing that you are not having performance problems just yet, I would not worry about it. "Don't fix what ain't broken". If you find that it is slowing down in the future, or it is bottle-necking on that function, then worry about it.

The query I gave should be pretty efficient.